# Godaddy wont take database names with periods in them. MVC EF models need renaming how?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created the databases first, then used the wizards in Entity Framework 5 to create the models from the Database first. Over time, through development, I made changes to the models and let EF recreate them by deleting my database and then starting the project up and they magically appeared again with the changes I made to the columns . It worked great on SQL Express 2014. But Godaddy doesnt let EF do that, AND I have databases with names like "Hazards.Models.CompanyDataContext" that EF made and didnt ask me what I wanted to name them. How do I change the code so it will let me rename the database it uses, and if possible, incorporate it into the aspnetdb that mvc uses as an additional table (there already is simplemembership etc. in there.)?

Comment: I ended up letting the local database update by EF and scripting the configuration and then running it at the Godaddy site.  This is a pain, but it was the only way to make it work that I of.

Comment: EF Code First or EDMX? For Code First just modify your DataContext class constructor to call base(yourConnectionStringName) and add the connection string to the Configuration File and rename your BD

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you used EF database first, rather than deleting your database and letting EF recreate it, have you thought about doing it the other way round?

You could use something like management studio express to rename your database tables/columns however you see fit. Then in Visual Studio, open your .edmx file, right-click the background and select 'update model from database'. This way you can add new tables to the model or update the models of existing tables from the database. Better still, you can take care of it all outside of godaddy.

Note: I found that when updating the EF model, just updating existing tables gives odd results sometimes. It's much more reliable when you delete tables from your .edmx first, then right-click and select 'update model from database', and add the tables back to your model.